# state_machine in rails 4 not proper initialize state column value

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, state-machine, acts-as-state-machine

I am learning Rails and try to use state machine but i am not able to initialize value for state variable..can anyone help me

```
class Primer < ActiveRecord::Base
    extend StateMachine::MacroMethods

    state_machine :initial => :data do
      event :ignite do
        transition :parked => :idling
      end
    end 
end
```

database schema

```
class CreatePrimers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :primers do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :state
      t.string :desc

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

try with

> rails c

```
 a = Primer.new
 => #<Primer id: nil, name: nil, state: nil, desc: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
2.2.0 :002 > a.state
 => nil
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like a known issue https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine/issues/334

And new gem suggested is https://github.com/state-machines/state_machines-activerecord